# Page.xml in Magento not Updating properly

Tags: jquery, html, magento, interface

I have been having problems trying to update my page.xml. I need to have this fix in order for my jquery plugins to work.

Basically in my text editor i have placed the jquery plugins below the jquery library and saved it.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>nanoScroll/nanoScroll.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>customScroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js</script></action>
```

But if i check the page and checked the view source, this is what i get.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cudsly.dev/js/nanoScroll/nanoScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cudsly.dev/js/customScroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cudsly.dev/skin/frontend/baby/default/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cudsly.dev/skin/frontend/baby/default/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cudsly.dev/skin/frontend/baby/default/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The plugin is on top of the jQuery library, causing this error -

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined nanoScroll.js:2

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call to

```
<action method="addJs"><script>nanoScroll/nanoScroll.js</script></action>
```

It's the same as making a call to

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><script>nanoScroll/nanoScroll.js</script></action>
```

Every "item" added to the header has a type.  Files of type `;` are located in the root level `js/` folder.  Files of type `skin_js` are located in the `skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/js` folder.  In your case `package` and `theme` are `baby` and `default`, respectively.

More relevant to your question: While Magento will render the items in the order they're added in the layout, Magento renders **all** the `js` items first, and then renders **all** the `skin_js` folder.  Because you (or your theme developer) has placed their copy of jquery in the theme folder, it will always render after items you add with `addJs`.

Your two choices are:

1. Move jquery into the `js/` folder, and change the `addItem` layout update call to a `addJs` call
2. Move your code in the theme folder and change your `addJs` layout update calls to an `addItem` call

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move `jquery.js` inside the js folder. There is no need to have it in the theme js files because jquery is the same for all the themes. After moving it just replace this line:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
```

with this one

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery.min.js</script></action>
```